# How would you implement sequences in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sequences

Does anyone have a good way of implementing something like a sequence in SQL server?

Sometimes you just don't want to use a GUID, besides the fact that they are ugly as heck. Maybe the sequence you want isn't numeric?  Besides, inserting a row and then asking the DB what the number is just seems so hackish.

Comment: This seems to address your question directly:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server (if it doesn't -- I must not be understanding some subtlety of your use case. Please comment)

Answer (score 53):

Sql Server 2012 has introduced [`SEQUENCE` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx), which allow you to generate sequential numeric values not associated with any table.

Creating them are easy:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Schema.SequenceName
AS int
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

An example of using them before insertion:

```
DECLARE @NextID int ;
SET @NextID = NEXT VALUE FOR Schema.SequenceName;
-- Some work happens
INSERT Schema.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)
  VALUES (@NextID, 'Rim', 2) ;
```

Comment: @eidylon, in previous versions of SQL Server it is possible to emulate the `sequence` object using dedicate table with `identity` column, as I explained in my answer. Though, in complex cases when you need to generate more than one value it gets pretty ugly.

Answer (score 16):

As [sqljunkieshare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092386/sqljunkieshare) correctly said, starting from SQL Server 2012 there is a built-in [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) feature.

The original question doesn't clarify, but I assume that requirements for the Sequence are:

1. It has to provide a set of unique growing numbers
2. If several users request next value of the sequence simultaneously they all should get different values. In other words, uniqueness of generated values is guaranteed no matter what.
3. Because of possibility that some transactions can be rolled back it is possible that end result of generated numbers will have gaps.

I'd like to comment the statement in the original question:

> "Besides, inserting a row and then asking the DB what the number just
>   seems so hackish."

Well, there is not much we can do about it here. The DB is a provider of the sequential numbers and DB handles all these concurrency issues that you can't handle yourself. I don't see alternative to asking the DB for the next value of the sequence. There has to be an *atomic* operation "give me the next value of the sequence" and only DB can provide such *atomic* operation. No client code can guarantee that he is the only one working with the sequence.

To answer the question in the title "how would you implement sequences" - We are using 2008, which doesn't have the `SEQUENCE` feature, so after some reading on this topic I ended up with the following.

For each sequence that I need I create a separate helper table with just one `IDENTITY` column (in the same fashion as in 2012 you would create a separate Sequence object).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SequenceContractNumber]
(
    [ContractNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SequenceContractNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContractNumber] ASC)
)
```

You can specify starting value and increment for it.
Then I create a stored procedure that would return the next value of the sequence.
Procedure would start a transaction, insert a row into the helper table, remember the generated identity value and roll back the transaction. Thus the helper table always remains empty.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewContractNumber]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @Result int = 0;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Procedure is called when there is an active transaction.
        -- Create a named savepoint
        -- to be able to roll back only the work done in the procedure.
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewContractNumber;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- Procedure must start its own transaction.
        BEGIN TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewContractNumber;
    END;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceContractNumber DEFAULT VALUES;

    SET @Result = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Rollback to a named savepoint or named transaction
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewContractNumber;

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

Few notes about the procedure.

First, it was not obvious how to insert a row into a table that has only one identity column. The answer is `DEFAULT VALUES`.

Then, I wanted procedure to work correctly if it was called inside another transaction. The simple [`ROLLBACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) rolls back everything if there are nested transactions. In my case I need to roll back only `INSERT` into the helper table, so I used [`SAVE TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx).

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a savepoint_name or transaction_name
>   rolls back to the beginning of the transaction. When nesting
>   transactions, this same statement rolls back all inner transactions to
>   the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement.

This is how I use the procedure (inside some other big procedure that, for example, creates a new contract):

```
DECLARE @VarContractNumber int;
EXEC @VarContractNumber = dbo.GetNewContractNumber;
```

It all works fine if you need to generate sequence values one at a time. In case of contracts, each contract is created individually, so this approach works perfectly. I can be sure that all contracts always have unique contract numbers.

NB: Just to prevent possible questions. These contract numbers are in addition to surrogate identity key that my Contracts table has. The surrogate key is internal key that is used for referential integrity. The generated contract number is a human-friendly number that is printed on the contract. Besides, the same Contracts table contains both final contracts and Proposals, which can become contracts or can remain as proposals forever. Both Proposals and Contracts hold very similar data, that's why they are kept in the same table. Proposal can become a contract by simply changing the flag in one row. Proposals are numbered using a separate sequence of numbers, for which I have a second table `SequenceProposalNumber` and second procedure `GetNewProposalNumber`.

---

Recently, though, I came across a problem.
I needed to generate sequence values in a batch, rather than one-by-one.

I need a procedure that would process all payments that were received during a given quarter in one go. The result of such processing could be ~20,000 transactions that I want to record in the `Transactions` table. I have similar design here. `Transactions` table has internal `IDENTITY` column that end user never sees and it has a human-friendly Transaction Number that would be printed on the statement. So, I need a way to generate a given number of unique values in a batch.

Essentially, I used the same approach, but there are few peculiarities.

First, there is no direct way to insert multiple rows in a table with only one `IDENTITY` column. Though there is a workaround by (ab)using [`MERGE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36553/how-do-i-insert-a-default-row), I didn't use it in the end. I decided that it was easier to add a dummy `Filler` column. My Sequence table is going to be always empty, so extra column doesn't really matter.

The helper table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SequenceS2TransactionNumber]
(
    [S2TransactionNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Filler] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SequenceS2TransactionNumber] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([S2TransactionNumber] ASC)
)
```

The procedure looks like this:

```
-- Description: Returns a list of new unique S2 Transaction numbers of the given size
-- The caller should create a temp table #NewS2TransactionNumbers,
-- which would hold the result
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewS2TransactionNumbers]
    @ParamCount int -- not NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Procedure is called when there is an active transaction.
        -- Create a named savepoint
        -- to be able to roll back only the work done in the procedure.
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewS2TransactionNos;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- Procedure must start its own transaction.
        BEGIN TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewS2TransactionNos;
    END;

    DECLARE @VarNumberCount int;
    SET @VarNumberCount = 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) dbo.Numbers.Number
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        ORDER BY dbo.Numbers.Number DESC
    );

    -- table variable is not affected by the ROLLBACK, so use it for temporary storage
    DECLARE @TableTransactionNumbers table
    (
        ID int NOT NULL
    );

    IF @VarNumberCount >= @ParamCount
    BEGIN
        -- the Numbers table is large enough to provide the given number of rows
        INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceS2TransactionNumber
        (Filler)
        OUTPUT inserted.S2TransactionNumber AS ID INTO @TableTransactionNumbers(ID)
        -- save generated unique numbers into a table variable first
        SELECT TOP(@ParamCount) dbo.Numbers.Number
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- the Numbers table is not large enough to provide the given number of rows
        -- expand the Numbers table by cross joining it with itself
        INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceS2TransactionNumber
        (Filler)
        OUTPUT inserted.S2TransactionNumber AS ID INTO @TableTransactionNumbers(ID)
        -- save generated unique numbers into a table variable first
        SELECT TOP(@ParamCount) n1.Number
        FROM dbo.Numbers AS n1 CROSS JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n2
        OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    END;

    /*
    -- this method can be used if the SequenceS2TransactionNumber
    -- had only one identity column
    MERGE INTO dbo.SequenceS2TransactionNumber
    USING
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        WHERE dbo.Numbers.Number <= @ParamCount
    ) AS T
    ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT DEFAULT VALUES
    OUTPUT inserted.S2TransactionNumber
    -- return generated unique numbers directly to the caller
    ;
    */

    -- Rollback to a named savepoint or named transaction
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureGetNewS2TransactionNos;

    IF object_id('tempdb..#NewS2TransactionNumbers') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #NewS2TransactionNumbers (ID)
        SELECT TT.ID FROM @TableTransactionNumbers AS TT;
    END

END
```

And this is how it is used (inside some big stored procedure that calculates transactions):

```
-- Generate a batch of new unique transaction numbers
-- and store them in #NewS2TransactionNumbers
DECLARE @VarTransactionCount int;
SET @VarTransactionCount = ...

CREATE TABLE #NewS2TransactionNumbers(ID int NOT NULL);

EXEC dbo.GetNewS2TransactionNumbers @ParamCount = @VarTransactionCount;

-- use the generated numbers...
SELECT ID FROM #NewS2TransactionNumbers AS TT;
```

There are few things here that require explanation.

I need to insert a given number of rows into the `SequenceS2TransactionNumber` table. I use a helper `Numbers` table for this. This table simply holds integer numbers from 1 to 100,000. It is used in other places in the system as well. I check if there is enough rows in the `Numbers` table and expand it to 100,000 * 100,000 by cross joining with itself if needed.

I have to save the result of the bulk insert somewhere and pass it to the caller somehow. One way to pass a table outside of the stored procedure is to use a temporary table. I can't use table-valued parameter here, because it is read-only unfortunately. Also, I can't directly insert the generated sequence values into the temporary table `#NewS2TransactionNumbers`. I can't use `#NewS2TransactionNumbers` in the `OUTPUT` clause, because `ROLLBACK` will clean it up. Fortunately, the table variables are not affected by the `ROLLBACK`.

So, I use table variable `@TableTransactionNumbers` as a destination of the `OUTPUT` clause. Then I `ROLLBACK` the transaction to clean up the Sequence table. Then copy the generated sequence values from table variable `@TableTransactionNumbers` to the temporary table `#NewS2TransactionNumbers`, because only temporary table `#NewS2TransactionNumbers` can be visible to the caller of the stored procedure. The table variable `@TableTransactionNumbers` is not visible to the caller of the stored procedure.

Also, it is possible to use `OUTPUT` clause to send the generated sequence directly to the caller (as you can see in the commented variant that uses `MERGE`). It works fine by itself, but I needed the generated values in some table for further processing in the calling stored procedure. When I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @TableTransactions (ID)
EXEC dbo.GetNewS2TransactionNumbers @ParamCount = @VarTransactionCount;
```

I was getting an error

> Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement.

But, I need `ROLLBACK` inside the `EXEC`, that's why I ended up having so many temporary tables.

After all this, how nice would it be to switch to the latest version of SQL server which has a proper `SEQUENCE` object.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2014/2/16/create-unique-invoice-number-in-sql.aspx) is another **similar article**, hope helps some one.

Comment: Did you create clustered primary key for faster query and what is `ASC` and `PK_SequenceContractNumber` in CONSTRAINT **[PK_SequenceContractNumber]** PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContractNumber] **ASC**) ?

Comment: @stom, the `SequenceContractNumber` table has a clustered primary key. `PK_SequenceContractNumber` is the name of the primary key constraint and corresponding index that is created to implement the constraint. `ASC` means ascending sort order of `ContractNumber` in the index. The main point of the method that I described here is that the helper table with `IDENTITY` column always remain empty. A row is inserted, the generated `ID` is recorded and transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 5):

[An Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) is roughly analogous to a sequence.

Comment: Roughly yes, but not quite. You need to insert something into the table before you can be sure of the ID.

Comment: perhaps I should have said "very, very roughly" :)

Comment: And you can also get gaps in your sequence, if you rollback an insert.

Comment: @JonasLincoln You can get gaps in a SEQUENCE, too.  There is essentially no way to ensure you will never get gaps.

Comment: An identity column works very well, especially combined with an OUTPUT clause to return the created ID value.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use plain old tables and use them as sequences.   That means your inserts would always be:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
SELECT number from plain old table..  
UPDATE plain old table, set the number to be the next number  
INSERT your row  
COMMIT
```

But don't do this.  The locking would be bad...

I started on SQL Server and to me, the Oracle "sequence" scheme looked like a hack.   I guess you are coming from the other direction and to you, and scope_identity() looks like a hack.

Get over it.  When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Comment: you would also need to use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE to guarantee that it works, but like @Corey Trager I also do not recommend that you implement this.

Comment: What seems hackish in sequences?  Just curious, I learned to use sequences first.  Like you mention, whatever we learn first tends to feel "right".

Comment: In SQL Server, I just specify the column as IDENTITY and I'm done.  In Oracle, I needed to do more (Sorry, I forgot the details.  It was 8 years ago...).

Comment: Ah, I see what your saying.  For Oracle that is correct, and it is a pain.  In Postgres, you can have a columns default value be the sequence's nextval, and it is very handy.

Answer (score 4):

The way that i used to solve this problem was a table 'Sequences' that stores all my sequences and a 'nextval' stored procedure.

Sql Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sequences (  
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    value BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT PK_Sequences PRIMARY KEY (name)  
);
```

The **PK_Sequences** is used just to be sure that there will never be sequences with the same name.

Sql Stored Procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'nextVal') AND type in (N'P', N'PC')) DROP PROCEDURE nextVal;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE nextval  
    @name VARCHAR(30)  
AS  
    BEGIN  
        DECLARE @value BIGINT  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION  
            UPDATE Sequences  
            SET @value=value=value + 1  
            WHERE name = @name;  
            -- SELECT @value=value FROM Sequences WHERE name=@name  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  
        SELECT @value AS nextval  
    END;
```

Insert some sequences:

```
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Workshop', 0);
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Participant', 0);
INSERT INTO Sequences(name, value) VALUES ('SEQ_Invoice', 0);
```

Finally get next value of a sequence,

```
execute nextval 'SEQ_Participant';
```

Some c# code to get the next value from Sequence table,

```
public long getNextVal()
{
    long nextval = -1;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
    try
    {
        //Connect and execute the select sql command.
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("nextval", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "SEQ_Participant";
        nextval = Int64.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        command.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    finally
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    return nextval;
}
```

Comment: Is this atomic?  If two callers called nextval at the exact same time, would they get the the same number?

Comment: This solution is not solving the concurrently request for a new id problem. If two or more clients call the nextval procedure at the same absolutely time then it is not clear what will be append. It is a solution for a small system. This solution solves only my pre known id problem, when insertind data.

Comment: This solution is not optimal. `nextval´should at least set an exclusive lock on the table. Otherwise two concurrent calls will return the same number.

Comment: @Clavijo -- Definitely not Atomic, yes two users could get the same value using the above code. I just posted an answer to this question that (i believe) does allow for Atomic sequences and handles concurrency issues.

Answer (score 3):

Sequences as implemented by Oracle require a call to the database before the insert.
identities as implemented by SQL Server require a call to the database after the insert.

One is no more hackish than the other. The net effect is the same - a reliance/dependency on the data store to provide unique artificial key values and (in most cases) two calls to the store.

I'm assuming that your relational model is based on artificial keys, and in this context, I'll offer the following observation:

We should never seek to imbue artificial keys with meaning; their only purpose should be to link related records.

What is your need related to ordering data?  can it be handled in the view (presentation) or is it a true attribute of your data which must be persisted?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012, you can simply use

```
CREATE SEQUENCE
```

In 2005 and 2008, you can get an arbitrary list of sequential numbers using a common table expression.

Here's an example (note that the MAXRECURSION option is important):

```sql
DECLARE @MinValue INT = 1;
DECLARE @MaxValue INT = 1000;

WITH IndexMaker (IndexNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 
        @MinValue AS IndexNumber
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        IndexNumber + 1
    FROM
        IndexMaker
    WHERE IndexNumber < @MaxValue
)
SELECT
    IndexNumber
FROM
    IndexMaker
ORDER BY
    IndexNumber
OPTION 
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a stage table with an identifier on it.

Before loading the stage table, truncate and reseed the identifier to start at 1.

Load your table. Each row now has a unique value from 1 to N.

Create a table that holds sequence numbers. This could be several rows, one for each sequence.

Lookup the sequence number from the sequence table you created.
Update the seqence number by adding the number of rows in the stage table to the sequence number.

Update the stage table identifier by adding the seqence number you looked up to it. This is an easy one step process.
or
Load your target table, add the sequence number to the identifier as you load in ETL. This  can take advantage of the bulk loader and allow for other transformations.

Comment: This is the right outline, but does not handle Concurrency issues.  I just posted some code in an answer that is transaction-safe and handles multiple current transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following snippet.

```
CREATE TABLE [SEQUENCE](
    [NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [NEXT_AVAILABLE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SEQUENCES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NAME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CLAIM_IDS (@sequenceName varchar(100), @howMany int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int
    update SEQUENCE
        set
            @result = NEXT_AVAILABLE_ID,
            NEXT_AVAILABLE_ID = NEXT_AVAILABLE_ID + @howMany
        where Name = @sequenceName
    Select @result as AVAILABLE_ID
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

As [sqljunkiesshare states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465306/3347858), sequences were added to SQL Server 2012. Here's how to do it in the GUI. This is the equivolent of:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Schema.SequenceName
AS int
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

1. In the *Object Explorer*, expand the *Programmability* folder
2. Under the *Programmability* folder, right click on the *Sequences*
   folder as shown below:

[image]

3. Underlined are the values that you would update to get the
   equivalent of the SQL statement above, however, I would consider
   changing these depending on your needs (see notes below).

[image]

Notes:

- The default Start value, Minimum value, and Maximum value were determined by the range of the data type which was an int in this case. [See here for more data type ranges if you want to use something other than an int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).
- Pretty good chance you'll want your sequence to start at 1 and you
  might want you minimum value as 1, too.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree and did this last year on a project.

I just created a table with the name of the sequence, current value, & increment amount.

Then I created a 2 procs to add & delete them.  And 2 functions to get next, & get current.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data with a sequential key, but you don't want to have to query the database again to get the just-inserted key, I think your only two choices are:

1. Perform the insert through a stored procedure which returns the newly-inserted key value
2. Implement the sequence client-side (so that you know the new key before you insert)

If I'm doing client-side key generation, I *love* GUIDs.  I think they're beautiful as heck.

```
row["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

That line should be laying on the hood of a sportscar somewhere.

Comment: I hear you. Everything has upsides and downsides. I'm actually a big natural key fan, so I usually only use GUIDs if no natural key is available. So a customer table would probably be PKed by SSN or a compound PK of name and address etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 you have the option of using Row_Number

Answer (score 0):

The other problem with an identity columns is that if you have more than one table where the sequence numbers need to be unique, an identity column doesn't work. And like Corey Trager mentions, a roll-your-own type of sequence implementation might present some locking issues.

The most straightforwardly equivalent solutions seems to be to create a SQL Server table with a single column for the identity, which takes the place of a separate type of "sequence" object. For example if in Oracle you would have two tables from one sequence such as Dogs <-- sequence object --> Cats then in SQL Server you would create three database objects, all tables like Dogs <-- Pets with identity column --> Cats. You would insert a row into the Pets table to get the sequence number where you would normally use NEXTVAL and then insert into the Dogs or Cats table as you normally would once you get the actual type of pet from the user. Any additional common columns could be moved from the Dogs/Cats tables into the Pets supertype table, with some consequences that 1) there would be one row for each sequence number, 2) any columns not able to be populated when getting the sequence number would need to have default values and 3) it would require a join to get all of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

By SQL you can use this strategy;

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SequenceFile]
AS int
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

and read the unique next value whit this SQL

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SequenceFile]
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRANSACTION SAFE !** For SQLServer versions before 2012... (thanks Matt G.)
One thing missing in this discussion is transaction safety.  If you get a number from a sequence, that number must be unique, and no other app or code should be able to get that number.  In my case, we often pull unique numbers from sequences, but the actual transaction may span a considerable amount of time, so we don't want anyone else getting the same number before we commit the transaction.
***We needed to mimic the behavior of oracle sequences***, where a number was reserved when it was pulled.
My solution is to use xp_cmdshell to get a separate session/transaction on the database, so that we can immediately update the sequence, for the whole database, even before the transaction is complete.

```
--it is used like this:
-- use the sequence in either insert or select:
Insert into MyTable Values (NextVal('MySequence'), 'Foo');

SELECT NextVal('MySequence');

--you can make as many sequences as you want, by name:
SELECT NextVal('Mikes Other Sequence');

--or a blank sequence identifier
SELECT NextVal('');
```

The solution requires a single table to hold used sequence values,  and a procedure ***That creates a second autonomous transaction*** to insure that concurrent sessions don't get tangled up.  You can have as many unique sequences as you like, they are referenced by name.  Example code below is modified to omit requesting user and date stamp on the sequence history table (for audit) but I thought less-complex was better for  the example ;-).

```
  CREATE TABLE SequenceHolder(SeqName varchar(40), LastVal int);

GO
CREATE function NextVAL(@SEQname varchar(40))
returns int
as
begin
    declare @lastval int
    declare @barcode int;

    set @lastval = (SELECT max(LastVal) 
                      FROM SequenceHolder
                     WHERE SeqName = @SEQname);

    if @lastval is null set @lastval = 0

    set @barcode = @lastval + 1;

    --=========== USE xp_cmdshell TO INSERT AND COMMINT NOW, IN A SEPERATE TRANSACTION =============================
    DECLARE @sql varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
    DECLARE @recorded int;

    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO SequenceHolder(SeqName, LastVal) VALUES (''' + @SEQname + ''', ' + CAST(@barcode AS nvarchar(50)) + ') '
    SET @cmd = 'SQLCMD -S ' + @@servername +
              ' -d ' + db_name() + ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, 'no_output'

    --===============================================================================================================

    -- once submitted, make sure our value actually stuck in the table
    set @recorded = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM SequenceHolder
                      WHERE SeqName = @SEQname
                        AND LastVal = @barcode);

    --TRIGGER AN ERROR 
    IF (@recorded != 1)
        return cast('Barcode was not recorded in SequenceHolder, xp_cmdshell FAILED!! [' + @cmd +']' as int);

    return (@barcode)

end

GO

COMMIT;
```

Now to get that procedure to work, you are going to need to enable xp_cmdshell, there are lots of good descriptions of how to do that, here are my personal notes that I made when I was trying to get things to work.  Basic idea is that you need xp_cmdshell turned on in SQLServer Surface Are a configuration and you need to set a user account as the account that the xp_cmdshell command will run under, that will access the database to insert the sequence number and commit it.

```
--- LOOSEN SECURITY SO THAT xp_cmdshell will run 
---- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
---- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
---- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
---- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO

—-Run SQLServer Management Studio as Administrator,
—- Login as domain user, not sqlserver user.

--MAKE A DATABASE USER THAT HAS LOCAL or domain LOGIN! (not SQL server login)
--insure the account HAS PERMISSION TO ACCESS THE DATABASE IN QUESTION.  (UserMapping tab in User Properties in SQLServer)

—grant the following
GRANT EXECUTE on xp_cmdshell TO [domain\user] 

—- run the following:
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'domain\user', 'pwd'

--alternative to the exec cmd above: 
create credential ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## with identity = 'domain\user', secret = 'pwd'


-—IF YOU NEED TO REMOVE THE CREDENTIAL USE THIS
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account NULL;


-—ways to figure out which user is actually running the xp_cmdshell command.
exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'osql -E -Q"select suser_sname()"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'osql -E -Q"select * from sys.login_token"'
```

Comment: SQL Server `SEQUENCE` objects are already transaction safe, though. If you pull a number from a sequence inside a transaction and someone else pulls one before your transaction is complete, they just get the next number along. Just like with Oracle, I believe. You may want to add your reasons for using this method rather than the built-in functionality...

Comment: @MattGibson - YES! Correct.  This code would only be useful to  people using SQLServer version Prior to 2012.