# Functional key and concurrency

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, azure

Context: web application, SQL Server / SQL Azure through EF Code first, asp.net mvc 3, windows azure.

I have a TPH table `company` which contains both customer companies and provider companies.
The table contains a column `type`, it's the table discriminator: `c` for customers and `p` for providers.

The primary key of the table is an auto incremented integer `id`, managed by the database.

Now I would like to have a functional compouned key, (`short_id, type`), where `short_id` is also an autoincremented integer but I don't know how and when generate `short_id` values to avoid concurrency issues.

How can I prevent two different customer companies to get the same `short_id` if one is entered in the database in new york at the very same time the other one is entered in paris.

```
id name       type  short_id
1  company_a  c    1
2  company_b  c    2
3  company_c  p    1
4  company_d  c    3
5  company_e  p    2
6  company_f  c    4
```

I know it's unlikely since the example is dumb but the question is technical.

Thank you for reading

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282943/how-would-you-implement-sequences-in-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Almost always, you'd split out customer and provider companies to different tables anyway (both pointing to the company table).

Comment: I have to agree with @Stu, here, that it is potentially better to have a Companies table and separate Customers and Providers tables. Apart from the fact that it would help with your problem, it also helps answer the question - what if a Provider becomes a Customer in the future (or vice versa)?

Comment: the example is not relevant, in my case tph is compulsory

Answer (score 0):

You might try this, though it could get slow if the table is large:

```
INSERT INTO company (name, type, short_id)
SELECT 'mycompany', 'c', ISNULL(MAX(short_id),0) + 1
FROM company
WHERE type = 'c'
```