# SQL Select and Update record during Insert

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Trying to `SELECT` and `UPDATE` a record inside a `SELECT` statement.
The Initial SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ATable(VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT B.VALUE1, dbo.FUNCTION(B.VALUE1)
FROM dbo.BTable B
```

The FUNCTION:

```
SELECT @nextNum = C.VALUE2
FROM dbo.CTABLE C
WHERE C.VALUE1= @VALUE1
RETURN @nextNum
```

What I am trying to do:

1. Insert a record into Table1.
2. Get data from Table2.
3. Also get a value for VALUE2 from another Table(CTable).

Problem:

I need to increment `VALUE2` each time this function executes so multiple calls to that record have a unique value.

I can't have a stored proc from inside the function, I can't have a stored proc inside the `SELECT`, and I can't call `UPDATE` from inside the `FUNCTION`.

Am I out of options?
Do I need a different implementation?

Comment: Are you trying to Insert one row into table `A` or many rows?

Comment: Insert what record into table 1? and whats table 2?

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: If I read this right, you want to use sequences. You might take a look at [How would you implement sequences in Microsoft SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282943/how-would-you-implement-sequences-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ATable(VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT B.VALUE1, C.VALUE2
FROM dbo.BTable B 
JOIN dbo.CTable C
ON B.VALUE1 = C.VALUE1
```