# Does this SQL Server stored procedure have concurrency issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

I'm using a stored procedure in SQL Server to get the next available number for a tenant. Here is the table, that holds the counter information:

```
CREATE TABLE [NumbersPool]
(
    TenantId [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    Counter [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNextNumber
    (@tenantId varchar(32)) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Counter AS BIGINT

    SELECT @Counter = Counter
    FROM NumbersPool WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE TenantId = @tenantId

    IF @Counter IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = 0

        INSERT INTO NumbersPool (TenantId, Counter) 
        VALUES (@tenantId, @Counter)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

        UPDATE NumbersPool
        SET Counter = @Counter
        WHERE TenantId = @tenantId
    END

    RETURN @Counter
END
```

Now the problem. The procedure seems to work fine with multiple concurrent calls (is called in a transaction with serializable isolation level), but at some point the counter jumps from e.g. 1992 to 25276 without any obvious reason.

Does anybody see any issues in it?

Comment: Why not use a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282943/how-would-you-implement-sequences-in-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: TABLOCK is the wrong lock hint.  Should be UPDLOCK, or TABLOCKX.  With TABLOCK you still get a shared lock, which will lead to deadlocks on UPDATE.

Comment: The table and the SP will become a hotspot if you have lots of concurrent request for the counter. So it can be the bottle neck for a highly concurrent system

Comment: The SP needs to be called in a transaction, or you should have BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT in your SP

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies and good suggestions!! @Larnu since I need a separate sequence for each tenant in our system I would need to create about a thousand sequences, so I thought a table might be simple to manage.